# How to display parameter in Web API help page for request and response body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, model-view-controller

I want to show request and response body as parameter not as raw data .
For that I have followed [Generate Description Fields for Body Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339077/generate-description-fields-for-body-parameters) answer but not get success , still showing

[image]

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets some very important data from the server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reqData">A Test Model</param>
    [HttpPost]
    public AccountService.GetAccountList_ResponseData GetAccountList([FromBody] AccountService.GetAccountList_ReqestData reqData)
    {
    }
    
    //--my modal
    public class GetAccountList_ReqestData 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// StartDate 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="StartDate">Describe parameter.</param>
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
    }
   
   //---Also enabled 
   config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WebApi.xml")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add XmlDocs to your class `GetAccountList_RequestData`

```
/// <summary>
/// My requestData model
/// </summary>
/// <param name="reqData">The description you want </param>
public class GetAccountList_ReqestData 
{
   /// <summary>
   /// StartDate 
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="StartDate">Describe parameter.</param>
   public string StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

You followed the steps correctly, however the person asking in the other thread was displaying a property. You on the other hand are asking for an object, which is your class. Therefor the xmldocs of the class will be used to generate the descriptions.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply @klekmek how i can add xml doc , can you  share any link to add xml doc for class

Comment: The XMLDoc is the `///` above your public class. Like illustrated in my code block.

Comment: /// <param name="reqData">The description you want </param> i have added this still i have get same result

Comment: Did you also add the `<summary>` part? All 4 lines

Comment: yes all 4 lines

Comment: You might have missed a step in the setup. I'd suggest following this link carefully https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages